# Can't extract response body to set env variable

Tags: json

I'm using Postman to pass the response from the body to the environment setup.  Can't get this one in particular to do so.

Response:

```
{
"AvailableTypes": [
    {
        "SubTypes": [
            2,
            1
        ],
        "Type": 0
    }
],
"PaymentInstruments": [
    {
        "Created": "2017-06-20T18:20:15.963Z",
        "CreditCard": {
            "Type": 2
        },
        "Id": 715886
    }
]
```

}

test:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("PID", jsonData.PaymentInstruments.Id);
```

Comment: You have an array.  You need to get one of its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the test:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("PID", jsonData.PaymentInstruments[0].Id);
```